# java DB and jar file

Tags: java, user-interface, javadb

we have a standalone project. we are using Java DB and we are writting our code on netbeans.
we can conncet to DB with using IDE and we can do what we want but when we make it jar file it couldnt connect to database . how can we solve this problem
thanks

Comment: Please provide the error you receive when executing your jar file, otherwise we can't help.

Comment: sure when we execute the file on the IDE we can register as a user but when we make it jar file we cant register . it doesnt reach the database

Comment: Do you have some kind of logging output/printed exception stracktrace which you can share? Otherwise we can just guess whats wrong.

Comment: How are you creating the jar file?

Answer (score 0):

The database driver has to be in classpath when you run your application as JAR. When you start the application in eclipse the driver is found in the build path. That's why your application works here.

Another solution would be to embed the driver's JAR in your JAR file.

Comment: how can I embed the driver's

Comment: I don't know how you are building your jar file... So I can't tell you how to extend your build to add the driver. I'm sure you will find a similar question here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

first check where is your jar located,most probably it is outside the project thats why error occurs. put them in your project and set path properly in classpath file like :

```
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="WEB-INF/lib/castor-1.1.2-commons.jar"/>
```

right now if you see your path is look like :

```
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="D:/apache-tomcat-6.0.14/apache-tomcat-6.0.14/lib/servlet-api.jar"/>
```

which is wrong.

provide your classpath file and error log if still error occurs.

Comment: I have checked it it is located in the project file . While netbeans open I can register and log in but when I closed the IDE I cant log in and register. I couldnt understand your explanation could you please extend more.

Comment: provide your .classpath file then explain issue if its same as i think

Comment: C:\Users\ARSLAN\Desktop\LanguageAid\dist\LanguageAid.jar this is the classpath of jar file.

Comment: here is the problem add your jar file in project folder with name lib folder and then change this particular path like  `path="lib/LanguageAid.jar"`

Comment: your program can not find location of jar file,do this for all jar files

Comment: I have changed the classpath like your says but nothing changed . still jar file couldnt reach the database